# kibana data table aggregate but no by all the fields

Tags: kibana-7

I have a request related logs in document, like:

- `request_id`
- `request_current_execution_time_ms` - it stores milliseconds from the beginning of request execution to the moment of log is written
- `request_url`
- `request_method`
- `response_status`
- `request_id_url` - this one is Scripted field of type URL, so clicking by that field it'll open discovery tab and show only logs related to specific request

What I want to do is to build a table where I want to list N last requests, group by request id, so basically my metric for data table is `request_id` Unique count.

In the table i want to show multiple rows:

- `request_id_url` - so we can click from the table and see all the logs related to particular url
- `request_url`
- `request_method`
- and `request_current_execution_time_ms`

But as `request_current_execution_time_ms` is can be many values for each log per request I add a filter by special log message `request_sent` to take only last log per request AKA full request execution time.

So I can build table by adding either `request_id_url` and `request_url` OR `request_id_url` and `request_method` OR `request_id_url` and `request_current_execution_time_ms` but can't add them all together, I'm simply getting error `error while executing search`... I think issue is that for each row it require own aggregation, but can I relay on other row aggregation and just show value I want? Or maybe I'm doing something else incorrectly?